Instability of aminodifluoroborane
So I was basically trying to formulate what I thought would be a stable, chemically unreactive, truly universal amphiphilic solvent, consisting of the aforementioned compound $\ce{F2BNH2}$. Finding information on something that obscure isn't easy but I did find at least enough articles talking about perfluorinated boron compounds that I am confident it does at least exist.
The problem is, these compounds apparently decompose rather readily, and I cannot comprehend why. As far as I can tell, every bond in them should be extremely strong and the compound as a whole should be linked together tightly due to hydrogen bonding between the polar half of the molecule. Fluorine and boron bond tightly, boron being more electropositive than hydrogen so that the fluorine doesn't form hydrogen fluoride, then nitrogen and boron bond readily as in boron nitride or ammonia borane, and the two hydrogens on the nitrogen should at least be somewhat stable I thought since its all a neutral compound and the fluorines in the compound would make it more electronegative on the whole.
But no, apparently I'm just incorrect and the whole thing dissolves quite readily, and try as I might I simply cannot fathom why. Can anyone help me?
As an extension on this question, does anyone have any tips regarding how I might find a chemically unreactive, highly stable, amphiphilic solvent (preferably with a capacity for hydrogen bonding).

Your F2BNH2 is essentially F3BNH3 after elimination of HF. Why should it be any better because of it? On the other hand, if one got eliminated, why not another?

I just was aware that boron compounds frequently lack a full set of four bonds, as do nitrogens given the existance of Ammonia. At any rate, the question goes equally for F3BNH3 if that would prove to be more stable. Albeit I do think that ruins any chance of it being amphiphillic, but at least understanding why it was unstable should help me try to find one that is more stable.

You're analyzing things individually, but not put together. For example, part of the reason the B-F bond is unusually strong in model compounds like $\ce{BF3}$ is back-donation from the fluorine lone pair into the empty trivalent boron orbital. If there is a nitrogen lone pair next to boron, this back-donation is severely suppressed, reducing the bond energy and favouring processes involving $\ce{F-}$ elimination. Furthermore, the N-H will become vastly more acidic than in $\ce{NH3}$, favouring reactive processes involving deprotonation. There's probably even more things to consider.

Did you consider DMSO as your amphiphilic solvent?

I don't think your compound, aminodifluoroborane $(\ce{BF2NH2})$, is unstable as you described  according to Ref. 1. The authors have prepared this compound (including their $\ce{^{15}N}$, $\ce{^{10}B}$, and $\ce{^{11}B}$ isotopic compounds) and analyzed them using gas-phased microwave spectroscopy (Ref. 1).
The preparation method was reacting gaseous $\ce{BF3}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ in an absorption cell at room temperature using two specific nozzles. A white crystalline solid has been formed on exposed surface of the cell. The X-ray crystallography (powder method) of this white crystal has suggested that it should be trifluoroborazane $(\ce{BF3NH3})$. The comparison with data from Ref. 2 has confirmed the structure. Microwave analysis of the dominant gas
phase product generated by heating crystalline $\ce{BF3NH3}$ to $\pu{140 ^\circ C}$ revealed that it is $\ce{BF2NH2}$, which has indicated that the molecular is planar having $C_{2\nu}$ symmetry:

It also has the dipole moment, $\mu. = \pu{2. 595 \pm 0.03 D}$.
Nicolau Saker Neto has given excellent explanation for the formation of $\ce{BF2NH2}$ from $\ce{BF3NH3}$, latter of which is the Lewis acid-Lewis base adduct to start with (see the comment in the post above). The structure of $\ce{BF2NH2}$ was comparatively similar to that of $\ce{BF2OH}$ and $\ce{BF2C#CH}$, at least the bond distance of $\ce{B-F}$ (see Table VII of Ref. 1). The partial double bond character of $\ce{B-N}$ bond has made it resistance to dissociate back to $\ce{BF3}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ at high temperature (Ref. 1). Thus, I'd say this compound should be at least fairly stable at room temperature (it is pretty stable in gas phase analysis conditions).
Note: For your question about amphiphilic solvent, I'd say try DMSO, which dissolve vast range of organic compounds. The other solvent I'm familiar with is sulfolane, which also dissolve tough aromatic compound such as perylenes.
References:

Frank J. Lovas and Donald R. Johnson, "Reaction of $\ce{BF3}$ with $\ce{NH3}$: Microwave spectrum of $\ce{BF2NH2}$,"  J. Chem. Phys. 1973, 59, 2347–2353 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1680343).
A. P. Caron, J. L. Ragle, M. E. Yorke, and H. Yeh, "Powder patterns and lattice constants of ammonia boron trifluoride and ammonium tetrafluoroborate,"  J. Phys. Chem. 1968, 72(2), 556–561(DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/j100848a029).

